# Magento Payment successful redirect issue

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-gateway, redirect-url

In my site I have issue in payment redirect URL.
It works **fine in Google Chrome** but it **redirects to empty cart page in Firefox**.

When I clicked on place order button, I redirect on Payment gateway page, after successful payment, the URL of site not going on Success page, it redirects on **Empty Cart Page**

Comment: I did not understand clearly

Comment: @AsishHira When I clicked on place order button, I redirect on Payment gateway page, after successful payment, the URL of site not going on Success page, it redirects on Empty Cart Page

Answer (score 1):

hello nikhil it can be happen because you are not getting success from your payment gateway same happened with me while using paytm so you go to your gateway module (magento) first check that the url where you are getting redirected is written where because in payment gateways usually we have :- success, cancel, failure functions so for that you will come to know about please tell are you using dummy account of payment gateway for testing

Comment: No I am not using any dummy accounts of payment gateway for testing, It works fine in CHROME. but not in Firefox.

Comment: use mage::log and check what response you are getting when it is coming back to you magento . can you give me the response you are getting i can help you properly